# Use something other than OS X Finder to zip iPhone app for submission

Tags: ios, macos, zip, application-loader

I'm trying to script the creation of the ZIP file required for Application Loader to upload to iTunes Connect.

If I use OS X's `zip` command, I get the message

> `The CodeResources file must be a symbolic link to _CodeSignature/CodeResources. Make certain that the bundle is on a locally-mounted volume (not a remote SMB volume), and be certain to use the Mac OS X Finder to compress it`

Sure enough, if I use Finder to compress my files, Application Loader doesn't complain and the upload is successful.

The ZIP files look identical in content and visible structure when examined.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps add `--symlinks` to your `zip` command. See `man zip` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In xCode4, I archive the app and submit it within Organizer, or if I have to give it to other people for submission, I can create an archive file from it, maybe a better way you can try?