# Can I pass on the iOS app in binary form to be code signed by third party for app store?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

As an independent iOS developer I would like to let my partners to sign the app themselves and handle the distribution. However I am not always in position to pass the whole project along with a source code (which might be confidential) for them to build. Are there steps in Xcode to make it possible?

I know I can make the critical part of the app a separate library to be linked to the whole project. It can be appropriate in some cases, however there are cases when I want to avoid the extra burden related to compatibility issues and code separation.

Answer (score 2):

This has always seemed like something that *should* be possible, but all the ways I've tried have failed so far.

What we do is to get the client to pass along a .p12 file containing their private key and distribution certificate, and the App Store mobileprovisioning profile.

We then build and sign the app, and pass it back to the client for them to upload using Application Loader. This has worked well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with Application Loader, I have been doing signing with provided cert, but so far had to perform the upload myself - ask the partner for their id/password. Anyway it doesn't solve my problem entirely. The typical situation is that sometimes the client wants to have the ability to replace some bundled resources (eg. images) without having to go back to me.

Comment: Ah interesting. I *think* you can change resources and re-sign the app, check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896029/re-sign-ipa-iphone