# Unable to identify iOS OSStatus Code

Tags: ios, iphone, security

I have a really strange behavior in an iOS App.
I switched from iOS 6 to iOS 7. In iOS 6 everything worked perfectly.

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)newSearchDictionary:(NSString *)identifier {
    NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [searchDictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];

    NSData *encodedIdentifier = [identifier dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [searchDictionary setObject:encodedIdentifier forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrGeneric];
    [searchDictionary setObject:encodedIdentifier forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
    [searchDictionary setObject:serviceName forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrService];

    return searchDictionary;
}

- (NSData *)searchKeychainCopyMatching:(NSString *)identifier {
    NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [self newSearchDictionary:identifier];

    [searchDictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];
    [searchDictionary setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];

    CFDataRef dataRef;
    OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary,
                                      (CFTypeRef *)&dataRef);

    if (status != errSecSuccess) {
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"%s - No OSStatus errSecSuccess. Caused by SecItemCopyMatching", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
#endif
        return nil;
    }
    NSData *result = (__bridge_transfer NSData *)dataRef;
    return result;
}
```

When the App starts the **- (NSData *)searchKeychainCopyMatching:(NSString *)identifier** function loads the values from the keychain. Everything works fine for a while. But after about 15 successful value requests I get an error.

**OSStatus Code -34018**

The SecItemCopyMatching function returns that error code. The documentation says

**@result A result code. See "Security Error Codes" (SecBase.h).**

But looking in the SecBase.h there are only these OSStatus codes specified.

```
enum
{
    errSecSuccess                               = 0,       /* No error. */
    errSecUnimplemented                         = -4,      /* Function or operation not implemented. */
    errSecIO                                    = -36,     /*I/O error (bummers)*/
    errSecOpWr                                  = -49,     /*file already open with with write permission*/
    errSecParam                                 = -50,     /* One or more parameters passed to a function where not valid. */
    errSecAllocate                              = -108,    /* Failed to allocate memory. */
    errSecUserCanceled                          = -128,    /* User canceled the operation. */
    errSecBadReq                                = -909,    /* Bad parameter or invalid state for operation. */
    errSecInternalComponent                     = -2070,
    errSecNotAvailable                          = -25291,  /* No keychain is available. You may need to restart your computer. */
    errSecDuplicateItem                         = -25299,  /* The specified item already exists in the keychain. */
    errSecItemNotFound                          = -25300,  /* The specified item could not be found in the keychain. */
    errSecInteractionNotAllowed                 = -25308,  /* User interaction is not allowed. */
    errSecDecode                                = -26275,  /* Unable to decode the provided data. */
    errSecAuthFailed                            = -25293,  /* The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct. */
};
```

The values doesn't get overridden, already checked.

And last but not least the search dictionary:

[image]

**Edit - new info**

I was debugging the whole day and I found some news. I'm downloading a Zip-File containing an executable Bundle. This is a In-House App so no worries about point 2.7 and 2.8 in the review guidelines. After successfully loading the bundle the entitlements error appears.

```
NSBundle *bundle = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
bundle = [[NSBundle alloc] initWithPath:bundlePath];
if (!bundle) {
    return nil;
}

// Here i can access the keychain as usually
[bundle loadAndReturnError:&error];
// Well here it suddenly doesn't work anymore
// error is also nil
```

Well the bundle code inside does not use the keychain. May be this is some kind of security logic? Any clues?

Comment: That is probably some kind of entitlement error se below:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344255/secitemadd-and-secitemcopymatching-returns-error-code-34018-errsecmissingentit

Comment: You are totally right. errSecMissingEntitlement in http://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55471/sec/Security/SecBasePriv.h

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project before rebuilding for ios7? Seems Xamarin users have experienced similar issues, however I dont think their solution works for you: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5807/problems-with-ios7-beta

Comment: Yes stayed the same. Also changed the devices.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates a problem with your app's entitlements. Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088460/keychain-integration-causing-crash-with-missing-entitlement-error-via-comma):  The cause is often that the App Identifier Prefix in the app's entitlements doesn't match the App Identifier Prefix in the provisioning profile.

To verify, use the codesign tool to view your app's entitlements:

```
codesign -d --entitlements - MyApp.app/
```

Then, compare the App Identifier Prefix to that in the provisioning profile:

```
cat MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision
```

Comment: Still the same behavior. It work's at the beginning, but after some attempts it fails

Comment: Maybe [these guys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344255/secitemadd-and-secitemcopymatching-returns-error-code-34018-errsecmissingentit/20508589?noredirect=1#comment31253057_20508589) can help you

Comment: I'll create a sample project that produces that behavior and upload it.