# Return errSecParam = -50 by using SecKeyRawSign in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, security

I'm going to make a security App, so sign certificate is necessary.

Follow the Apple document [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeyRawSign) the only way to Sign a Data is to use SecKeyRawSign and verify data with SecKeyRawVerify

> func SecKeyRawSign(_ key: SecKey, _ padding: SecPadding, _ dataToSign: UnsafePointer, _ dataToSignLen: Int, _ sig: UnsafeMutablePointer, _ sigLen: UnsafeMutablePointer) -> OSStatus
>
> func SecKeyRawVerify(_ key: SecKey, _ padding: SecPadding, _ signedData: UnsafePointer, _ signedDataLen: Int, _ sig: UnsafePointer, _ sigLen: Int) -> OSStatus

According to the API from Apple, I already can generate key pair.

The below is my function called getSignature()

```
func getSignatureBytes(plainText: String) {
    var result = [UInt8](count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    var resultLength = result.count

    let SignData = [UInt8](plainText.utf8)
    let SignLength = SignData.count

    let status = SecKeyRawSign(privateKey!, SecPadding.PKCS1SHA1, SignData, SignLength, &result, &resultLength)
    let status2 = SecKeyRawVerify(publicKey!, SecPadding.PKCS1SHA1, result, Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH), &result, resultLength)
}
```

After I finished the function, I make some UnitTest

```
func test_EC() {
    let b = TestEC()
    b.GenerateKeyPair()
    print(b.GetKeyTypeInKeyChain("tagPrivate"))
    b.getSignatureBytes("sdljaorjgpoa")
}
```

Here is the console return. 
At first, I generate key with RSA1024bits, it seems work!

So, I print the SecKeyRawSign OSStatus, return -50 [Meaning about OSStatus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816995/unable-to-identify-ios-osstatus-code) , it is errSecParam.

[image]

Hope to get some suggestions!!!

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out!