# Updating Xcode yields error "cannot find code object on disk" during codesigning

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, xcodebuild

I just updated to the newest version of Xcode and encountered an error while running our automated build scripts (they use the `xcodebuild` and `xcrun` commands).

The error occurs immediately after the `### Codesigning '/Users/...` log statement and looks like this:

```
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [/var/folders/__/63j90nkn2lg18ct1nq791_nc0000gn/T/g5hbigh1tM/Payload/CurrentTarget.app: replacing existing signature
/var/folders/__/63j90nkn2lg18ct1nq791_nc0000gn/T/g5hbigh1tM/Payload/CurrentTarget.app: cannot find code object on disk
```

I found docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html) listing and briefly describing the error but no specifics about how to resolve it.

Because I spent far too long looking for the resolution to this (nothing on S.O.) I'm going to post the answer below in case others encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's worth noting that you may need to update the environment variable that specifies the location of codesign_allocate:

```
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
```

But the real solution for me came from [here](http://pennysmalls.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/cannot-find-code-object-on-disk/):

```
ln -s /usr/bin/codesign_allocate /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
```

Hope this saves someone some time...

Comment: Glad it helped! I looked around for far too long and was worried I'd have to rewrite a whole bunch of AutoBuild code.

Answer (score 6):

I had this error when running a build script on XCode 4.5 (installed at /Applciations/XCode4_5), with XCode 5 installed more recently (in the main dev directory at /Applications/XCode) so that I can still target the iOS 6 SDK on an older project when needed.

I had previously applied the workaround mentioned in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18768869/72176 to my build script, by exporting the `CODESIGN_ALLOCATE` environment variable.

In this recent instance of this problem, I actually fixed it by *removing* the old workaround.  So my advice: if you get this error recently, and you've previously applied the workaround: try unapplying it and see if that helps!

Comment: Thank you! **Removing** a pre-existing export of `CODESIGN_ALLOCATE` in my build script resolved the issue for me.

Comment: yep export no longer needed, open a new terminal tab to clear

Answer (score 1):

The `cannot find code object on disk` error occurred on two of my projects after an update to Xcode 9.3.

**Case 1:** The issue was found to be CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY `-`.

[image: Code Signing Identity]

The fix was to change `-` to something specific.

In the Xcode Project Inspector, "Code Signing Identity" becomes either `Don't Code Sign` or some code sign identity.

Thus `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` `"-"` becomes either `""` (to not code sign) or a specific code sign identity.

**Case 2:** When using the Swift 4.1 *development snapshot* toolchain, the solution was to add a `.xcconfig` Configurations Settings File to the Xcode project. The default `CODESIGN_ALLOCATE` was set to the swift-4.1-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-….xctoolchain/usr/bin path which does not contain the `codesign_allocate` executable. The `.xcconfig` can expressly set `CODESIGN_ALLOCATE` for the build.

*example.xcconfig*

```swift
// file: example.config
CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
```