# "cannot find code object on disk" error in delphi xe5 with xcode5

Tags: xcode5, delphi-xe5

I recently upgraded from XE4 to XE5 and Xcode 4 to Xcode 5.0.2.
Both upgrades were done succefully. However when i now try to compile an iOS application for device, it reports the following errors.

```
[PAClient Error] Error: E0264 Unable to execute '"/usr/bin/codesign" --en "/Users/RezaRa/RADPAServer/scratch-dir/RezaRa-RezaRa/iziShoppingList.app/Entitlements.plist" -s "iPhone Distribution: Mohammad Sanati (XXXXXX)" -f "/Users/RezaRa/RADPAServer/scratch-dir/RezaRa-RezaRa/iziShoppingList.app"' (Error 1)

[PAClient Error] Error: E0264 /Users/RezaRa/RADPAServer/scratch-dir/RezaRa-RezaRa/iziShoppingList.app: cannot find code object on disk
```

The latest version of Xcode 5 and the Command Line Tools are installed. I have used the help files to check if everything is configured and installed as it should be and it is.
Compiling to the simulator also seems to work. Al certificates are installed and validated.

Any idea?

Comment: I found the solution in this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768819/updating-xcode-yields-error-cannot-find-code-object-on-disk-during-codesigning

Comment: If you found the solution, then you can delete the question.

Comment: Hi @PRUZ it would be a good idea for others to find this post easily, I was searching for the solution for hours and I haven't found that post. SO I think the question and keyword is more straight forward than the other pots, BTW if I need to delete the question let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this code in terminal

```
ln -s /usr/bin/codesign_allocate /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
```

Comment: Yes I know I have answered my question in my comments