# iOS 9.0.2 - Can't Install Enterprise App -Unable to Download App (app name) could not be downloaded at this time

Tags: ios, enterprise-distribution

My company has an app that can be downloaded through a website using Enterprise Distribution.

In iOS 9, tapping the download link brings up the expected pop-up "(website) would like to install (App Name)". Tapping 'install' on that dialog first causes the app to get stuck "Waiting..."

App stuck waiting

Until it finally indicates: "**Unable to Download App (app name) could not be downloaded at this time**."

Unable to Download the App

Installing works as expected using **iOS 7** and **iOS 8**.

How do we support Enterprise Distribution in **iOS 9**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to download application. <Appname> could not be installed at this time"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266418/unable-to-download-application-appname-could-not-be-installed-at-this-time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple has silently changed how Enterprise Distribution works several times, so knowing the answer to this question will not actually benefit you in the long run. How to find the answer to your question the *next* time will benefit you most.

Connect your device with the shiny new iOS version to your Mac running Xcode, and open the Devices organizer. Select the device, and optionally clear the log. Now open your app distribution page and try to install the app (clear any previous versions of the app off the device first), and keep an eye on the log output. Here you will find hints as to what you need to change.

For iOS 9.1, I saw the error: `BundleValidator: Failed bundleIdentifier: com.example.appName.XXXX does not match expected bundleIdentifier: com.example.appName`, which means that the `bundle-identifier` in the project `plist` file did not match the Bundle Identifier from the project. I remember adding `.XXXX` to the bundle identifier in the `plist` file last time I had to fix Enterprise Distribution, for iOS 8.0, i think. Fixing this was easy, just remove the offending `.XXXX` -- but then it dosen't work for iOS < 9.0

For the time being, I maintain two `plist` files for distributing the same `ipa` file, one for iOS 8.+, and another for iOS 9.+

Comment: We adjusted the bundle identifier as well, works with iOS 8.4 and iOS 9.x. In iOS 8, we could enter any bundle identifier, didn't matter at all.

Comment: In iOS 8, the bundle identifier had to be different each time, or the app would not install. That was what the .XXXX was for in my example