# iPhone application Could not download on IOS 10

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, ios10

i'm new to this website and new to Xcode and IOS development. i have an application thats can be downloaded with a weblink for Iphones, the application is working perfectly but if any device with ios 10 or higher can't download the application. at first the application the app ican appears after a while i get a messeage that it's can't be downloaded.
any suggestions?

Comment: If your app is designed for Enterprise, this question is possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/33407082

Comment: Capital letters are there to make what you write easier to read, not more difficult for you to write.

Answer (score 0):

It is the case of signing cerificates. Your provisioning profiles should be correct and make sure udid of the devices must be added.