# Unable to Download 'AppName' could not be downloaded at this time

Tags: ios, mobile, enterprise, ios9.3, enterprise-distribution

I have an enterprise app that I'm distributing via OTA. When I try to install it I get this error from Xcode Device Log :

```
 LoadExternalDownloadManifestOperation: Canceling failed manifest
 download for replace: [MyBundleID]
 [MIClientConnection uninstallIdentifiers:withOptions:completion:]: 
 Uninstall requested by itunesstored (pid 2029) for identifier MyBundleID with options:
```

[image: Device Error Message]

This is my manifest.plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://myDomain/api/iosEventAppLink/EventApp.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>xxx.com.domain.EventApp</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>AppName</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you archived it for ad-hoc distribution?

Comment: I arhived it  for enterprise distribution

Answer (score 5):

For anyone trying to get more information on why this happened:

- connect your iDevice to your Mac
- "Trust" your Mac on your iDevice
- Open console.app on your Mac
- On the left, select your iDevice under "Devices".
- To clear the noise, on the top-right search for: "process:appstored" without the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure of options while exporting archive to create .IPA file.
**Use either "Save for Ad Hoc Deployment" or "Save for Enterprise Deployment".**
I faced same error "Unable to Download App could not be downloaded at this time" when I used option "Save for iOS App Store Deployment" to create .IPA file and tried to install the app through a website.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I haven't confirmed iCloud password when prompted. So make sure you confirm iCloud password and also restart device and try again. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This question has a solution for the same error message.
["Unable to download application. <Appname> could not be installed at this time"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266418/unable-to-download-application-appname-could-not-be-installed-at-this-time)

I have suffered from this issue as well. In my case, there was a problem with the certificate on the device. I had to remove it and reinstall.