# iOS Provisioning Profiles

Tags: ios, ipad, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I developed an iOS app for a customer over a year ago and recently the customer contacted me saying the app was no longer loading.

The provisioning profile had expired and they had gone into the setting and removed the profile. The app now no longer loads.

I have renewed my iOS developer profile but I can't figure out how to restore the provisioning profile to the app to get it working.

The further complication is that I no longer have all of the source code so can't just rebuild the app. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: haven't saved it somewhere in the organizer (Archives)? so you could re-assign it. you need either the project in your organizer or saved it as xcarchive, only with an ipa it's not possible as far as I know because it is signed and hashed

Comment: well i do have most of the code but the latest version got lost after deploying to the ipad so I'd have to do some work in getting it up to date... i was hoping i'd be able to just 'drop' a new provisioning profile onto the app on the ipad. Is that not possible?
, thanks jim

Comment: take a look to this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896029/re-sign-ipa-iphone

maybe it helps ^^

Comment: did it helped you? or problem still remaining?

Comment: i found the latest code but then on trying to deploy it to the ipad i got 'a valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found' i created a new provisioning profile in the dev centre, then, refreshed the profiles in xcode organiser, then dragged and dropped the new profile onto the ipad. I was then able to deploy the app to the ipad... many thanks for your help and comments