# Distributing apps from two different Macs using the same dev and team profile

Tags: ios, xcode, in-house-distribution

I am trying to distribute an in-house enterprise app from my other mac, which is a mac pro. I exported the dev profile following [Apple's instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html) from my macbook that I have been using to distribute successfully. I imported them on the mac I am trying to distribute from now also following those instructions.

I copied the project folder from my macbook (working distribution) to mac pro (not working) and opened it with Xcode. I then built and archived the project. I then went to Organizer, selected the latest archive, and clicked `Distribute...`

From there I did what I always do: Select the second option for Enterprise, use the proper provisioning profile, and export it to the server it's being hosted on.

When I click the link to install the app it starts to download just fine but finishes with the weird no icon image as the app icon and when I try to open it the app just immediately closes.

Did I do something wrong in exporting and importing my profile(s)? If not, what else could be the issue here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After hours on the phone with Apple, hours searching forums, and hours of toying with things myself I finally decided to just try to create a new project from the second mac, the MacPro. I created a bundle ID and provisioning profile for it. I downloaded the profile, placed it in Xcode, archived the project, went through the distribution process using said provisioning profile and sure enough the app worked!

This told me that I had actually done the exporting and importing correctly. There was nothing wrong with the mac itself; **the problem must've been with the project!** I created a new project and simply copied all the individual files over and went through that project's distribution and sure enough it installed and launched without a hitch.

I still don't know what it is about the original project itself that causes it to behave in that manner. I assume there must be something in the project that ties it to the mac on which it was created. From now on I guess I'll either have to save the project on a server or some central location or just keep it on the mac from which it was created.

Comment: I am glad that you were able to solve the problem with a brute force method. From now on I would suggest that you inspect the log files when something is behaving unexpectedly. It might save you hours and hours and hours.

Comment: I agree that the logs can be very helpful. However, they were not what led to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please post what is written to the device log while the installation is taking place. You can monitor the device console from the Organizer window in Xcode. Open Xcode and select *Window -> Organizer* then select *Console* under your device.

Based on your description I can think of three things that may have caused this:

**OTA Over SSL**

The device attempting to install the app is running iOS 7.1 and the *manifest.plist* and *ipa* are not being served over SSL. Please keep in mind that iOS 7.1 now requires OTA installations to take place over a secure **https** connection.

**Signed with Incorrect Profile**

If the device log contains "Unable to preflight application" then the application was most likely not signed appropriately. You can verify that you are indeed using the correct mobile provision by following the steps from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18642782/1144060

1. Take your IPA file, rename it to have a .zip extension.
2. Unzip this file and open the Payload directory in Finder.
3. Right click your application and click Show Package Contents.
4. Find the file *embedded.mobileprovision*, and open this file in a text editor (like TextEdit).

If the *embedded.mobileprovision* contains an entry for *ProvisionedDevices* then you are signing with an Ad Hoc or development profile and not with your enterprise profile.

**Missing Private Key**

Unless the enterprise certificate is managed by Xcode (e.g. you created the enterprise certificate from within Xcode) it is likely that Xcode does not manage it in the same way it manages your other profiles.

Our build machine has multiple ADC accounts configured in XCode 5. When attempting to initialize a new build environment I exported the profiles and imported them into the new build environment. The enterprise certificate and key were not created by one of the accounts registered in Xcode. The enterprise certificate and key were not transferred.

On your macbook open *Keychain Access.app* and selected the *Certificates* Category on the lower left. Your enterprise certificate will be shown in relation to the private key. Select both of them and then select *File... -> Export*. Enter a password to protect the p12 file.

Copy the resultant p12 file (Named *Certificates.p12* by default) to your mac pro and double click the file to import it into your default keychain using *Keychain Access.app*

Comment: Sorry I am just now commenting on this. I have been very busy. I checked the *embedded.mobileprovision* and it has a value of `true` for `ProvisionedAllDevices`. So there is not an issue there. I have also done the exporting of my certificates. They are identical on both Macs. Also, my site has SSL. I know this because when I distribute from my Macbook Air I am able to install fine.

Comment: What does the console output say while installing the app and when attempting to launch the app? You can find out how to access these logs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1747/_index.html