# ios enterprise distribution : could not installed at this time

Tags: ios, swift, enterprise

I'm trying to distribute the app using  Enterprise Developer.

Its working on ios 8 devices

But i got error when trying to install on ios 7 device.

These are the error messages on xcode organizer console :

```
<Error>: profile not valid: 0xe8008012 
<Error>: 0x283000 install_embedded_profile: Could not install embedded profile: 0xe8008012  
<Error>: 0x283000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.YORUKn/foo_extracted/Payload
```

plist xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>items</key>
        <array>
                <dict>
                        <key>assets</key>
                        <array>
                                <dict>
                                        <key>kind</key>
                                        <string>software-package</string>
                                        <key>url</key>
                                        <string>https://{url_to_file.ipa}</string>
                                </dict>
                        </array>
                        <key>metadata</key>
                        <dict>
                                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                                <string>{bundle name}</string>
                                <key>bundle-version</key>
                                <string>1.0</string>
                                <key>kind</key>
                                <string>software</string>
                                <key>title</key>
                                <string>{apps name}</string>
                        </dict>
                </dict>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Note configuration :

- Build Active Architecture Only = NO
- Code Signing Identity = Iphone Distribution (*profile enterprise )
- iOS deployment Target = iOS 7.1
- Xcode 6.0.1

How do i install / distribute app to ios 7 device ?

Comment: Is the device in question 7.0.X?  Also which are you using: an ad-hoc or in house distribution certificate?

Comment: iOS 7.1 device. and use in-house distribution certificate.

Comment: Try using the verification steps [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642302/cant-install-enterprise-app-to-devices-with-unregistered-uuids)

Answer (score 0):

solved. Try to re-Download a developer profile and set to Target -> general -> identity -> Team.

Thanks!