# Issues signing PhoneGap IPA for distribution

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store-connect, code-signing, code-signing-entitlements

I've run into an issue signing an update on my PhoneGap generated IPA for distribution.

I have been following the same steps I typically use by clearing the PhoneGap signing, resigning using a distribution profile, attaching Entitlements.plist, then signing using my enterprise certificate but when I use the Application Uploader I get the following error.

```
ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application's signature
contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, 
value "[TEAMID]. [Bundle Identifier]" for key "application-identifier" in
"Payload/Application.app/Application" is not supported. This value should 
be string starting with your TEAMID, followed by a dot '.', followed by 
the bundle identifier" 
at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
```

Now the Bundle ID is identical to that of the App's distribution provisioning profile and the one on iTunes Connect. My TEAMID totally matches the one provided in the provisioning profile.

*This app is already in the store, I am trying to release an update.*

*I have installed the new profile to Xcode 4.6.3 and my certificate is also installed there.*

*I am using Terminal on Mavericks to unsign->resign->zip the IPA for distribution.*

I have looked around for a while and have found some other issues and after following their resolutions I am still stuck on this error, which it turn generates a couple other generic errors.

***Thanks in advance for any pointers/reference!***

I have spent all day fussing about with this issue :(

Comment: It appears that your application identifier is receiving the value, "[TEAMID].[BUNDLEIDENTIFIER]" instead of your actual Team ID and Bundle  Identifier. Is your project file maybe missing these values?

Comment: Do you have two certificates? I have a app-store sign key and an in-house app sign key. This will cause a lot of confusion, because you cannot see which one is used, because they are named exactly the same. We also needed to switch the keystore for every build.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi I was just using a generic name for them in this post but I can ensure you that they are the genuine ones

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach Yes, we have one that is used in PhoneGap to compile the IPA but I am resigning using a process similiar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896029/re-sign-ipa-iphone)

The difference with mine is I'm creating Entitlements.plist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this issue by reissuing my certs/profiles, reinstalling them, clearing my derived data, restarting my computer, and finally completing the resigning process.