# Re-sign ipa for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to re-sign an existing ipa file with new mobileprovision and distribution certificate. I am following these links[re-sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896029/re-sign-ipa-iphone) and [this](http://www.rsaunders.co.uk/2013/09/re-siging-app-store-bundles.html). However these require distribution certificate to be installed. **Can I re-sign the ipa without installing the certificate in KeyChain?** Something similar to passing the certificate details (password) in command line.

Comment: Do you mean: Revoke the Provisioning Profile ?

Comment: @Raptor: No, I meant I want to resign the app as mentioned in the mentioned links but do not want to do it from installed key chain certificate. I want to sign without installing the certificate in keychain

Comment: I see. Re-sign vs Resign.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can not specify the certificate using command line arguments. You must need to import the Distribution Certificate into Keychain first. Once installed, you can resign the app via command line arguments.