# Re-Sign App Store apps with Development profile

Tags: ios, code-signing

I have got an IPA file for an App that used to be in the App Store but no longer is. I am a developer and would like to try and use my wildcard Development provisioning profile to re-sign this app so I can install it on my registered iPhone.

I have tried following steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921689/3703938 however there are two problems. The app doesn't have an `embedded.mobileprovision` file or an `Entitlements.plist` file.

I copied over my development provisioning profile and renamed it `embedded.mobileprovision` then ran codesign. It installed on my iPhone however as soon as I open the app it crashes. Inspecting the crashlogs shows it's a codesign error: "`EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL - CODESIGNING)`"

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I would go about using the `codesign` command to re-sign this app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XCode 5 and have a team provisioning profile, this really shouldn't be a problem. Check these items:

1. On the "General" tab ensure that your actual team is showing in the "Team" option (right under "Build").
2. In the "Build" tab, under "Code Signing" make sure that you have "None" set for "Provisioning Profile" and "IOS Developer" set under "Code Signing Identity".

If this doesn't work, then ensure that your device is indeed added to your team profile. Press CMD+SHIFT+2 to bring up the organizer, select your device on the left, and then select "Add to Member Center" on the bottom.

Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you understood my question sorry. I have an IPA file (no source code) and I'm trying to re-sign it to install on my iPhone using my team Development provisioning profile using the `codesign` command line tool.

Surely, if I don't have the source code, I can't build & sign with Xcode? Hence why I am just trying to re-sign using the command line as per linked question. Problem is it doesn't contain the plist and embedded.mobileprovision files so it's not codesigning properly

Comment: Oh. Stupid me. I apologize for missing that! Can you download an older version of the Xcode tools that works with entitlements? Otherwise I'm not sure what to suggest.

Comment: The problem is the app IPA itself doesn't contain an `Entitlements.plist` or an `embedded.mobileprovision` so, whilst I can gen a new code signature using `codesign` and it installs on my iDevice, it obviously hasn't codesigned properly as it just crashes on app open (giving Codesign error). Stuck as to where to go next!