# Distributing ipa without re-compiling for Apple's Enterprise Developer Program?

Tags: ios, ipad, adhoc, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution

So, we have a few versions of working ipa's on TestFlight from our freelancer programmer. Every feature was tested out thoroughly. But once we have someone else compile the source code, something is always missing. Now we are thinking about distributing it through an Enterprise Developer Program. (We haven't decided since we are not 100% sure yet).

So I want to know, is there any way to reuse the previous ipa without recompiling it, so that we can move it from our current company developer program to enterprise, and distribute from there? Because if we hire someone to compile it, a lot of the functions will break again, it will be expensive and time-consuming to fix.

I asked the Apple's support, they told me to come here.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just download the .ipa from Testflight and reupload that to whatever new platform you want?

If you can get that file and upload it somewhere else, it should work just the same.

Comment: Thank you Adama, the Enterprise license requires different provisioning profile. As I heard, it has to be compiled into the new ipa in order to be distributed outside of the App Store. So I am wondering, if there is any service like TestFlight, that can append this enterprise profile, without me recompiling the ipa?

Comment: Ah, that makes it a bit more difficult. 

It looks like someone here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896029/re-sign-ipa-iphone) was having a similar problem. You may be able to follow the accepted answer on that page (green check mark) and unzip, unsign, resign, re-zip the ipa as outlined in that answer.

Comment: Hi Adama, you are really helpful! I will send this to my programmer and see if this approach can help us get the app to the users.