# How do you allow third party to publish your iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, publishing

I have a client with an apple developer account.  Its brand new and we are both new to Apple.

He has paid to developer an iphone app.

The developer wants to publish the app directly to the store.

The client does not want to share login details for the account.

What options are there?

I am asking because I know on Google Play Developer console you could invite someone to manage your account (or give them publishing priviledges) by inviting them using their gmail email via the console.

Comment: This sounds like a contractual dispute. Was the developer paid to develop the app and supply the source code to the client, or was the developer paid to provide only a compiled app in the app store? Either way, the two parties have to come to an agreement regarding their proper roles and the ownership of the code. None of this has to do with an actual programming problem, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about a contractual dispute.

Comment: no thats your opinion. the question is what it is no hidden meaning so dont look for one.  its straight forward.  How does a third party publish app on someone else appstore account

Comment: In order to publish an app, you need to be the team agent for the account under which the app is being published. If the client won't share the team agent's credentials and the developer won't give the client what they need in order to build the app themselves, then they're at an impasse. There's no technical solution for the situation you've described; the parties have to come to an agreement. Hence, it's a contractual matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Re-sign IPA (iPhone)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6896029/643383)

Comment: no cos im asking HOW to do it, not what the legalities are realting to this procedure

Comment: The indicated duplicate explains HOW you can provide only a compiled app to your client so that they can put it in the App Store without having the source code. But again, YOU cannot publish an app under someone else's account unless they provide the team agent credentials.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest solution. Tell your client to change his password and give you the new password. Publish the app on iTunes, tell your client to change his password back. If he doesn't trust you enough to give you a half-hour access to his account, why on earth does he trust you to write the app in the first place.

Next easiest solution (assumes you have a paid up account.) You publish the app on your account and mark it so it doesn't automatically go in the store after approval. Once the app is approved, transfer ownership to him. There are a whole bunch of restrictions on this process, including No iCloud, Passbook or in-app purchase subscriptions. For more details, Google "Transferring and Deleting iOS Apps" or see [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html]

Next easiest solution would be to give the customer access to the source and explain to him how to build the app and put it in the store.

-- Addition --
A new solution is available now. The client could give you admin privileges to his appstore (https://appstoreconnect.apple.com) account.

Comment: the client has paid for compiled app not the source code, only the developer has the source code

Comment: Good thing I gave you options that don't require releasing the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to this funny question is to let your client share his screen with logged in account at iTunes Connect (via Team Viewer for example). You do all your job and it's all.