# Sign ipa for iOS App with Client provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have an iOS app I created for a client. The client has provided me with a distribution provisioning profile, a .p12 key and a developer certificate.

I now want to sign my app using the provisioning profile provided by the client. I have previously signed my other apps with provisioning profile from my Apple id. I need to know how I can sign it with the client provisioning profile.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-sign IPA (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896029/re-sign-ipa-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Install client certificate on your system and set the certificate and provisioning profile in signing.[image: Signing]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I installed the certificate. the Signing authority does show the name of the distribution certificate. But the Provisioning profile shows "Unknown"

Comment: Is there a way I can check if the provisioning profile is successfully installed?

Comment: Iphone Configuaration utility 

http://iphone-configuration-utility.soft32.com/mac/

Comment: So your provisioning profile dropdown only shows "Unknown"?  The profile you were sent isn't available to choose as an option?  You can check if the provisioning profile was installed by looking in the directory at `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`

Comment: @VishalKalola looks like the tool is no more available with iOS8

Comment: its mac software not mobile software. install on your system. at the time its giving error but ignore that error and install anyway. its work fine.

Comment: @VishalKalola It does not install. It says installation failed

Comment: The last screen that shows message `"The installation failed" The installer encountered an error that caused installation to fail.Contact software manufacturer for assistance`

Comment: @wottle thanks for the answer. The Profile seems to have installed. But I still cannot see it in the drop down list while signing the ipa

Comment: if its already install then another way is import manually in Provisioning Profiles above screen

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to login in Xcode account with the account from that team?

`Xcode` -> `Preferences` -> `Accounts` and add account that connected to your team.

Comment: Its the client account and I would not have access to it

Comment: They can invite you to their team and give you "developer" role.