# Resigned IPA is not verified correctly by codesign

Tags: ios, iphone, release, ipa, codesign

I have an IPA file exported for development and I want to sign the IPA file using a valid enterprise certificate. Actually, I have gone through all the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896029/re-sign-ipa-iphone#) amd [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896029/re-sign-ipa-iphone#) and used various available tools such as [ota-tools](https://github.com/RichardBronosky/ota-tools) and [iResign](https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign) to sign the file.

The app is actually a very small swift app and only uses app groups and key-chain sharing capabilities and is developed by members of my enterprise team using the App ID and team identifier that we have defined using Xcode in our enterprise account.

I have done the resigning process without any problem and the app is installed successfully on my iPhone. But it immediately crashes upon startup.

So, I doubted the resigning process and did some checks. I tried to check the resigned IPA file using 'codesign -v' command but it says "code object is not signed at all".

I also unzipped the IPA file did all the code-signing on the main app and Frameworks folder but still head no luck with codesign verification. it still says "code object is not signed at all".

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem where the app won't start after resigning and installing. Did you have any success resolving this problem?

About the codesign verification, if you've successfully installed the app on the phone that means that the resign is OK. Also you should run the 'codesign -v' command on the .app itself in the ipa file, because that's the file you're actually signing, the ipa is just a zip you create after the resigning.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (resigned app crashed on launch). I figured out that this happens only for IPAs with embedded bitcode.

Removing bitcode support from project settings (`ENABLE_BITCODE = NO`) fixes the problem.

I understand that this is limitation, for this reason I opened an [issue](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15594) on `fastlane sigh` (the main tool I use for resigning) on Github.