# Resign an ipa or, xcarchive

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a requirement to deploy an enterprise application to my users. Vendor has give me an IPA/Xcarchive file. But, the files are signed using vendor’s signing certificate. We don’t want to share our distribution certificate with them and, they are unable to share the xcode with us. I want to know, how can I resign ipa/xcarchive for in-house distribution?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Chetan

Answer (score -2):

Certificates and provisioning profile used for generating IPA contains all the details on which all devices it can be installed, so it is not possible to resign the IPA file without the source code. Below are few available options:

1. **Get the source code:** If you can get the source code then you can generate IPA file with your certificates.
2. **Share Device UDID:** You can share the device UDIDs wherein you want to install the app with the vendor (might not be a good option for large audience)
3. **TestFlight:** You can ask the vendor to upload the app on Testflight and add the users as testers/users and they will be notified for any update available aswell.

Comment: But, I see articles posted here that explains how can we resign an IPA or, XCARCHIVE. Is my case different?

Comment: Maybe you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896029/re-sign-ipa-iphone