# XCode / iOS : how to test with XCode (on a real device) an app developed by another developer?

Tags: xcode, code-signing

I work with another developer. I would like to test its app but I don't have its iTunes Connect login / password and I don't have its dev certificates.

How can I test on my real device the bundle he sent to me without having many signing errors ?

I want to perform the test in Xcode in order to be able to use the debugger and perform some code modifications. I do not need to test the inapp purchase, just the core features of the app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resigning an iOS provisioning profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634188/resigning-an-ios-provisioning-profile)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to resign the app with your own certificates.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20637775/2475902)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use XCode7 Beta, it allows you to install any apps they develop on their devices without an Apple Developer Program Certificate.